# FileChooserListView kivy disable expande function

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser

I'm using FileChooserListView to be able to navigate inside a folder and choose a file from it. I'm using filters and if statements so that when I click on a folder it directly open a certain sub folder and displays only yaml files inside it.

This part is working fine when I enter a certain folder, but the problem is that, when expanding the folder by clicking on the small arrow on the left it displays the folders that I want to filter out.

My questions:

1. How can I disable this expanding function?
2. If it is not possible, How to include the filtering also in this part?

````
    def open_entry(self, entry):
        path = os.path.join(entry.path, "maps")
        # set filters back to show all
        self.filters = []
        if os.path.exists(path):
            # if inside maps folder show only yaml files
            self.filters = ["*.yaml"]
            entry.path = path
            return super().open_entry(entry)
        path = os.path.join(
            os.path.expanduser("~"), "catkin_ws", "src", "my_sites", "sites"
        )
        if entry.path != path:
            entry.path = path
        return super().open_entry(entry)```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you set `filter_dirs` to `True` for your `FileChooserListView`, then you can use `filters` to determine which folders will or won't be displayed. As described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html#kivy.uix.filechooser.FileChooserController.filters), you can use patterns or a call-back function for filtering.